# Vuex: Access data from store in component's lifecycle hooks

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex

How can I access data from vuex store in my component lifecycle hooks? For example, user can view this page if he/she is admin, otherwise redirect the user to another page. Below are my files
*Please ignore irrelevant comments in code, can't post mostly code and I don't think I need more comments than I already have*
*I also want to specify that I'm at the beginning with both vue and vuex*
**vuex.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: { // state
        user: null
    },
    getters: { // geters
        user: (state) => {
            return state.user
        }
    },
    actions: { // actions
        user(context, user) {
            context.commit('user', user)
        }
    },
    mutations: { // mutations
        user(state, user) {
            state.user = user
        }
    }
})
```

**Admin.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- All these give back the user like this (based of what I store in user object)
        {
            "name": "Admin1",
            "email": "email@test",
            "role": "admin"    
        }
        --->
        {{ user }} <!-- displays object -->
        {{ getUser1 }} <!-- displays object -->
        {{ getUser2 }} <!-- displays object -->
        {{ getUser3 }} <!-- displays object -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default ({
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['user']),
        getUser1() {
            return this.user
        },
        getUser2() {
            return this.$store.getters.user
        },
        getUser3() {
            return this.$store.state.user
        }
    },
    created() {
        // All this statements give back null
        console.log(this.user) // null
        console.log(this.$store.state.user) // null
        console.log(this.$store.getters.user) // null
        console.log(this.getUser1) // null
        console.log(this.getUser2) // null
        console.log(this.getUser3) // null
    }
    // Same output in mounted()
})
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import router from './router.js'
import store from './vuex.js'

import './axios.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Please show your `main.js`. We cannot see how Vuex is imported

Comment: My bad, I forgot. Thank you for pointing that out @tauzN

Comment: in your main you import from `vuex.js`, but in your example you call it `store.js`. Typo or error?

Comment: That was my mistake when I wrote the question, thank you for pointing that out @muka.gergely. I made a typo, it is indeed vuex.js. I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet below you can see that the data is available from the `created` lifecycle hook (so, "pretty early"). (Also, it's best practice to init your `Vuex` store state with a **function**.)

```js
const initialState = () => ({
  user: {
    "name": "Admin1",
    "email": "email@test",
    "role": "admin"
  },
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: initialState(),
  getters: {
    getUser: (state) => state.user
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      userBeforeCreate: null,
      userAtCreated: null,
      userBeforeMount: null,
      userAtMounted: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.getUser
    },
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log("before create")
    const user = Object.freeze({ ...this.user
    })
    this.userBeforeCreate = user
  },
  created() {
    console.log("cretead")
    const user = Object.freeze({ ...this.user
    })
    this.userAtCreated = user
  },
  beforeMount() {
    console.log("before mount")
    const user = Object.freeze({ ...this.user
    })
    this.userBeforeMount = user
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted")
    const user = Object.freeze({ ...this.user
    })
    this.userAtMounted = user
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      beforeCreate:
      {{ userBeforeCreate }}
      <hr />
      created:
      {{ userAtCreated }}
      <hr />
      beforeMount:
      {{ userBeforeMount }}
      <hr />
      mounted:
      {{ userAtMounted }}
      <hr />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So, I think the problem is not that the `getters` are not "ready".

---

If your beginning state is `null`, then you have to "fill" it somehow - the best way is to `dispatch` the `action` you planned to do the thing.

In your example code nothing is dispatching an action - eventually you get the beginning state of `null` with the getters.

```js
const initialState = () => ({
  user: null,
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: initialState(),
  mutations: {
    SET_USER(state, data) {
      state.user = data
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setUser({
      commit
    }, data) {
      commit("SET_USER", data)
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: ({
      user
    }) => user
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      userAtCreated: null,
      userToSet: {
        "name": "Admin1",
        "email": "email@test",
        "role": "admin"
      },
    }
  },
  created() {
    // calling the method that dispatches the action
    this.setUser()
    this.userAtCreated = this.$store.getters.getUser
  },
  methods: {
    setUser() {
      // dispatching action here
      this.$store.dispatch("setUser", this.userToSet)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      USER IN STORE:<br />
      {{ userAtCreated }}
      <hr />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

SUGGESTION: DO NOT give `mutations`, `actions`, `state` items & `getters` the same name. That might mess up things (at least when you're thinking / talking about them).

---

If, on the other hand, you are using `axios` to get the data & only dispatch the action somewhere else, then it might make sense, that at `created()` the getter returns `null`: the data might have simply not arrived by the time `created()` is called.